# npm install -g cordova ionic bower gulp not working on windows

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, npm-install

I was trying to install cordaova ionic bower and gulp on windows system
when I type npm install -g cordova ionic bower gulp on git-bash
It doesn't show any progress either error nor result.

Have set PATH inside Environment variable->System variable->Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
and also C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users******.npm-packages

[image]

Comment: Have you actually tried to run, for instance, `gulp -v`?

Comment: @miparnisari yes,output is                                                                          $ gulp -v
[11:06:35] CLI version 3.9.1